# Multiple Usercontrols with slight difference

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls, readonly-attribute

I'm using three `UserControls` that have a datagrid. One of the `UserControl's` `DataGrid` needs to have a column readonly attribute set to `True`.

Right I'm doing this after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
v_uc1.v_datagrid.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = true;
```

Is there a cleaner way (XAML) to do this?

Comment: If the datagrid the same for the 3?

Comment: can you post the xaml you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make just one UserControl with properties that expose the differences between them, such as

```
public class MyUserControl
....

public bool IsColumn1ReadOnly{
    get{ return v_uc1.v_datagrid.Columns[1].IsReadOnly;}
    set {return v_uc1.v_datagrid.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = value;}
}
```

then in XAML you would instantiate the control like this:

```
<my:MyUserControl IsColumn1ReadOnly="True"/>
<my:MyUserControl IsColumn1ReadOnly="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a data grid column to read only in xaml do the following

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Comment: Please flesh out your answer.